# Set relationship and inverse with one statement or two

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, one-to-many

In core data, if you set the relationship in one direction, do you need to also set the inverse relationship or is it set automatically?

I have a one to many relationship in both directions.  I'm setting it as in first example below but want to be sure it is set in both directions.  The reason I'm suspicious it is not getting set properly is that predicates work properly in some spots but not others so want to isolate if this is source of the bug.

```
//code to select book from existing books

//Create relationship with author
IS this sufficient?

NSSet*existingBookInSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:bookForAuthor, nil];
_author.book = existingBookInSet;
```

Or do I need to do:

```
NSSet*existingBookInSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:bookForAuthor, nil];
_author.book = existingBookInSet;
NSSet*authorSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:_author, nil];
bookForAuthor.author = authorSet;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the relationships are defined as inverses of each other. Then setting one relationship will automatically set the other.

The naming you've chosen is a bit confusing. We generally use plural nouns for to-many relationships. And I'm not sure what will happen if you pass an NSSet to your setter instead of an NSMutableSet. I'd rather see something like

```
book1.author = author;
book2.author = author;
NSLog(@"%@", author.books);
... prints the set of two books
```

Or if you'd rather work the other direction:

```
NSMutableSet *authorBooks = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:book1, book2, nil];
author.books = authorBooks;
NSLog(@"%@", book1.author);
... prints the author
```

You don't need both of these, just one, as long as the model correctly defines the inverses. Note that per Apple documentation, every Core Data relationship needs an inverse.

Comment: In other words, the first code sample should be sufficient, provided the model specifies that `book` and `author` are inverse relationships.

Comment: Correct. See my expanded answer.

Comment: Where do Apple's docs say that every relationship needs an inverse? That wasn't the case in the past, and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) only says that inverses are recommended.

Comment: Continue reading to the "Inverse Relationships" and "Maintaining Object Graph Integrity" sections. Also see the WWDC presentations on Core Data, where that point is made often.

Comment: The strongest statement I find is: *You must define many-to-many relationships in both directions—that is, you must specify two relationships, each being the inverse of the other.* And since the OP's question seems to cover many-to-many relationships, that's a fair point. However, it's both possible and valid to create a Core Data relationship (even a to-many relationship) that lacks an inverse, so I still think your last line is too strong.